# Switch to SQL membership provider from AD membership provider runtime

Tags: asp.net, membership, provider

In my asp.net application admin functionality, I am trying to combine AD authentication and form authorization for creating the users, roles and Assign users to roles etc. I have configured MembershipADProvider and AspNetSqlMembershipProvider in my web.config with MembershipADProvider as the default one. After user logs in using AD authentication, I need to switch/assign my membership object to use AspNetSqlMembershipProvider in order to get all the users from membership object (from dbo.aspnet_Users table). How do I switch the provider during run time? I have tried different approaches after searching for this issue and none of that seem to work for me so far.
Here are couple of approaches I tried:
1. foreach (MembershipProvider mp in Membership.Providers)
            {
                if (mp.Name == "MembershipADProvider")
                {
                    Membership.Providers.Remove(MembershipADProvider");
                    MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
                    ddlUsers.DataSource = users;
                    ddlUsers.DataBind();
                    break;
                }
            }

Membership.Providers.Remove(MembershipADProvider"); - doesn't work as it's not supported..
Also, tried to clear the Membership.Providers and then add only the type of AspNetSqlMembershipProvider which are also not supported.

1. I can't set Membership.Provider with value from 
   Membership.Providers["AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"] as Membership.Provider is a read only property.
2. I tried to swtich the connection string between 2 providers, which didn't swtich the provider, as both are different types of providers..if both were sqlserver providers this would have worked I believe.

Please let me know if anybody has successfully implemented or if at all this is a plausible approach. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would pass an explicit provider to your code, rather than taking a dependency on Memebership directly (which just wraps the one flagged as default in the config). There is no need to swap them in and out at runtime, think how this would affect thread safety.

So rather than saying `Membership.GetAllUsers();` you would do something like (I don't have a compiler to hand):

```
public UserSerivce : IUserService
{
   private MembershipProvider provider;

   public UserService(MembershipProvider provider)
   {
       this.provider = provider;
   }

   public IEnumerable<MembershipUser> GetUsers()
   {
       return provider.GetAllUsers();
   }

   public void DoSomethingElseUseful()
   {
       ...
   }

}
```

And then to use it for a particular provider:

```
var service = new UserService(Membership.Providers["mySqlMembershipProvider"]);
var users = service.GetUsers();
```

Or if using AD specific code:

```
var service = new UserService(Membership.Providers["myADMembershipProvider"]);
var users = service.GetUsers();
```

Using DI in this way also helps keep code testable.

Comment: Thank you for your response, TheCodeKing! This approach looks cleaner, once it works. I did try referring to a particular provider earlier (within the class, not the service approach) like  -                               Membership.Providers["ASPNetSqlRoleProvider"].GetAllUsers() - but Provider.GetAllUsers() expects arguments such as int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords. Membership.GetAllUsers() calls the base function which has no arguments. I tried passing parameters like Provider.GetAllUsers(1, 1, out val), but it didn't work. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: If you look in reflector `Membership.GetAllUsers()` just calls `Membership.GetAllUsers(0, 2147483647, out num)`. It's probably not a good idea to try and load all the users for performance reasons. It's better to page through the results.

Comment: I did look in the reflector for membership object's GetAllUsers() earlier and yes it does call Membership.GetAllUsers(0, 2147483647, out num). It didn't strike me to make a call using the exact code. Now, after you pointed that again I tried using                                                           users = Membership.Providers["AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"].GetAllUsers(0, 2147483647, out val); and it worked! Is this OK to call with parameters (0, 2147483647, out val)? But, this does work! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If all you need a list of users in the aspnet_Users table, just connect to your database with `System.Data.SqlClient` objects and query the table.  There is no reason (that you mentioned) you need to use a membership provider to get that data.

Having said that, your membership/authentication scheme sounds like it may have some design issues, perhaps best tackled in a different question, but I think it might be useful to you if you sought comment on what you are trying to accomplish overall with the multiple membership providers.

Edit:  I found some potentially useful posts on using multiple membership providers.  It looks like the general idea is to implement custom code handling the `Login.Authenticate` event on your `Login` control, and use `Membership.Providers["ProviderName"].ValidateUser` to attempt authentication with each provider.

http://www.stevideter.com/2008/03/20/using-two-membership-providers-for-aspnet-logins/
http://forums.asp.net/p/1112089/1714276.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I agree, I can use System.Data.SqlClient and query the table to populate the list of users. But, I was trying to achieve this using sqlserver provider to save some work..but if this is not at all possible, then I might have to take that route. Also, if I just use the sqlserver provider for login as well as admin functionality, then also I am able to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I think I looked up something similar to this earlier, which talks about authentication using both the providers which is comparatively easier. I tried this approach earlier as  MembershipProvider userProvider = Membership.Providers["ASPNetSqlRoleProvider"];
userProvider.GetAllUsers(1, 1, out val); which didn't work.